# Unhandled loop exception when moving frames around in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-7

If I start at my standard java view and then I move one of my open programs to the side  (so I can see 2 open programs at once, side to side), and then I click on either of the frames, I get

```
unhandled event loop exception
Item not added
```

I then get the following in the event detail's stack trace -

```
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_17
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Error
Sat Apr 20 00:36:50 EDT 2013
Unhandled event loop exception

org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: Item not added
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar.createItem(ToolBar.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolItem.<init>(ToolItem.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.fill(ActionContributionItem.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.update(ToolBarManager.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionSetActionBars.setActive(ActionSetActionBars.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.ui.SubActionBars.activate(SubActionBars.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.SubActionBars.activate(SubActionBars.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionPresentation.setActionSets(ActionPresentation.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.updateActionSets(WorkbenchWindow.java:1886)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$ActionSwitcher.updateActionSets(WorkbenchPage.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$ActionSwitcher.updateActivePart(WorkbenchPage.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$ActionSwitcher.updateTopEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:637)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActiveEditorSources(WorkbenchPage.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActivations(WorkbenchPage.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$15(WorkbenchPage.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$2.run(PartServiceImpl.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartActivated(PartServiceImpl.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.AbstractPartRenderer.activate(AbstractPartRenderer.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer$1.handleEvent(ContributedPartRenderer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1447)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_MOUSEACTIVATE(Shell.java:2328)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4572)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2069)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessage(OS.java:3129)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3753)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? If I go back to a single program view at once it seems to work fine, but I really want to see both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [an-swt-error-has-occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156802/an-swt-error-has-occurred)
More details in Eclipse [bug# 287508](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=287508)